# How to react on changes in one way bindings

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

In the following snippet:

```
angular.module('myModule')
        .component('myComponent', {
            controller : [
                 MyComponentController
            ],
            bindings: {
               input: '<'
            }
        });
```

According to [documentation - section "Components have a well-defined lifecycle"](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) in order to monitor that the binding `input` has changed we could use `$onChanges` lifecycle method. I can't make it work.

Thi is how I am using it:

function MyComponentController() {
        self.$onChanges = function (changesObj){
              // some code here
        }
    }

But the code doesn't even enter the fuction.

Comment: How are you trying to modify the binding? It'd help to see that part of the code too.

Comment: @JoeClay I just got to this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14030 It seems that I am doing it all well just the Angular v. 1.5.0 has a bug. It should be working in 1.5.3. I am gonna give it a try.

Comment: @JoeClay It was indeed the bug. But the release notes state that it was corrected in v.1.5.4. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#154-graduated-sophistry-2016-04-14

Comment: Ah, it's not a bug causing it then! The $onChanges hook actually wasn't added until version 1.5.3. The only hook that was available in 1.5.0 was $onInit.

Comment: Good for you! I have updated the answer with your comment. If you post the answer I am gonna set your answer as correct.

Comment: Posted as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we figured out in the comments, the issue was that the `$onChanges` hook (along with `$onDestroy` and `$postLink`) was not added until version 1.5.3 of Angular, and zatziky was using 1.5.0, which only implements the `$onInit` hook. Seems a bit strange for them to add such a big feature in a patch level release, but at least it was an easy fix.

Answer (score 1):

It was a bug corrected in version [1.5.4](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#154-graduated-sophistry-2016-04-14).

However, I am using version **1.5.3** and it is working. Strange...

**Update**

***@JoeClay*** has noticed that it was not a bug at all. The `$onChanges` was added in version 1.5.3.